# Cannot find terminal in android studio

Tags: android, git, macos, android-studio, terminal

I am using macOS X. I was using android studio in it. It was doing great before,but from today, when I open my android studio project, this is not showing any terminal on it. I can't find it from view> Tool Windows.

Comment: short cut is alt + f12 on windows

Comment: i am using mac osX

Comment: go to settings->keymap-> search terminal on top .  it will show what shortcut is assigned to terminal

Answer (score 0):

Go to `file->settings->keymap-> search terminal on top` and it will show the shortcut assigned . Here is a pic for your understanding . You can also change the shortcut if you want .

[image]